# How do you validate an entry into rails database with preset values that already exists in a database or another database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example Lets say you wanna store some phone numbers into the database. But you only want to accept the phone number if it starts with a certain area code. Lets say the area code is `123`. I want to be able to accept/reject that phone number depending if it starts with `123` and don't care what comes after.

I know how to validate it using model validations, but its annoying to change the model validations once the area code gets much bigger in scale.

How would I validate the phone numbers by `storing an area code into a database/using a database` and then testing it against a new entry of a phone number?

Comment: You could try it using something like a `constants.rb` file that's in the rails config/initializers path. In that file you can define an array constant with whatever area codes you want and check against it in the model validation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your application, there will be a settings/constant information to save information that are frequently changed. If,not you can create a key value pair general settings, where they key could be area code and the value 123.

Then you can use this to validate the phone no, this way if area code changes, all you have to do is update the value in general settings for key 'area_code'.